# Full image won't show in CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-cardview

I am using `CardView` in Android Studio and I want to use `ImageView` in it to show some images but the problem is it doesn't show the full image. I want to scale it to show the full image.

Here is part of my code:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="more"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <a.extera.CustomTxtView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_more"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="more" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                />

                <a.extera.CustomTxtView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_more2"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="more" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                  />

                <a.extera.CustomTxtView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_more3"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="more" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <a.extera.CustomTxtView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_more4"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="more" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

                <a.extera.CustomTxtView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_more5"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="more" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> for example this is the full image:

!https://s32.postimg.org/mntlijbn9/a_2.jpg

> this is what it shows:

!https://s32.postimg.org/s6fyuyd91/image.jpg

Comment: Try using `fitCenter` instead of `centerInside` in the `android:scaleType` attribute?

Comment: i also used fitCenter but still dosent show the full image

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the current behavior and the desired behavior?

Comment: i post the screenshots link above

Comment: You didn't specify an orientation for your LinearLayout, which might lead to unwanted results. And have you tried removing fitsSystemWindows from your ImageView?

Comment: i specified android:orientation="horizontal" which nothing showed at all and with android:orientation="vertical" is the same result as before , and i also removed fitsSystemWindows but nothing happened

Comment: I didn't mean the orientation on your ImageView (which is weird though) but on the wrapping LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:scaleType="centerInside"` in ImageView to `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: i changed it but nothing happend

Comment: Change **android:layout_width="match_parent"** in ImageView to **android:layout_width="wrap_content"**

Comment: when the mobile is landscape it shows nearly all of the image but when it's portrait only show part of the image